# Wordpress won't show posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm really new to PHP and Wordpress. My posts won't show up and I don't know how to fix it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>

  <?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        // Your loop code
    endwhile;
else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
?>

        </div> <!-- /.blog-main -->

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div> <!-- /.row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is my index.php

My url: http://st358373.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/epw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` inside the loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // Your loop code
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
    else :
    echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
endif;
?>
```